# loading Focebook profile pictures in circle view - bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

i am new to iOS and i have a problem. I am using parse.com as my backend and i have a bug loading my Facebook profile img. I want to add the picture into a UIImage view and make the view a circle. I download the image using URLrequest https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1 and i put the image into imageData. Are there any tutorials how to accomplish this? I want it like this http://ewebdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/110.jpg //the profile picture. Thank you for help.

Comment: why would it be a bug if you are just not capable of implementing a basic visual effect...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All answers are true!
The only thing they all missed is that the picture's width must be equal to height, i.e. 
it must be squared, otherwise your image will be like oval.
So get profile image with same width and height, e.g.
https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=square&width=120&height=120

Answer (score 0):

Import `QuartzCore.framework` into your project, Set your UIImageView `layer.cornerRadius`to your desired value and set `layer.masksToBounds = YES;` to achieve rounded  shape image view.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = yourImageView..size.height/ 2;
yourImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
UIImage *image = //Image from API
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = image.size.width / 2;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[self.view addSubview: imageView];
```

Comment: Thank it works but not correctly, the shape doesn't look like a circle but like a lemon :D u put the code above into - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

Answer (score 0):

Here the code to download a picture from Facebook:

```
// Specify link parameters
NSMutableString *link = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/"];
[link appendFormat:@"%@/picture", userId];
[link appendFormat:@"?height=%d&width=%d", pictureHeight, pictureWidth];

// Send request to load image
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
NSMutableURLRequest *pictureRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:pictureRequest
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:
 ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

   if (connectionError) {

     // Process error;
   } else {

     UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageWithData:data scale:scale];
     return picture;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use [FBProfilePictureView](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBProfilePictureView/) for your project, this is sample project [facebook-ios-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)

How to set circle view,

1) add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

2) setup value of FBProfilePictureView class:

```
profilePic.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0;
```

Hope to help you.